# Improve javascript code performance by reducing selector duplication

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working with javascript and in my project I have those 2 lines:

```html
$('#content').on('click', 'input[type=submit]', function(){

$('#content').on('click', 'a.removebutton', function(){
```

I would like to reduce selector duplication for optimization but when I try, the code below It does not work:

```html
var selector = $('#content').on('click');

selector.('a.removebutton', function(){...
```

Kindly help me solve this problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var selector = $('#content').on('click', 'input[type=submit]', function() {...});
selector.on('click', 'a.removebutton', function() { ... });
```

Or a more "fluent" equivalent:

```
$('#content')
  .on('click', 'input[type=submit]', function() {...})
  .on('click', 'a.removebutton', function() { ... });
```

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface

Comment: Thanks. wih the second `.on('click...`, my IDE tells me this `Unresolved function or method on()`. Any thing to say about it ?

Comment: Can you paste your code into a jsfiddle? I'll take a look, perhaps you're missing a parenthesis somewhere

Comment: Ah.. ok watch the use of semi-colons. Note how in lines 1 & 2 of my "fluent" example I haven't put semi-colons. That's because the whole thing is effectively one statement. We want to chain the output of each function to the next one.

Comment: I do not get what you are saying. Can you edit the fiddle for me to see it ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117505/discussion-between-chardy-and-prince).